# Firebase data security

Tags: firebase

Good afternoon, I wonder if it is possible in firebase to allow reading and writing a file from a given URL?

Example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true, // www.myweb.com.br
    ".write": true // www.myweb.com.br
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot, it is actually pointless to do that, as a malicious user will replicate the whole request and edit the source origin to `www.myweb.com.br`.

To achieve the desired behavior that nobody outside of `www.myweb.com.br` can access your database. you simply have to set only `www.myweb.com.br` as an authorized authentication domain, this way even if somebody took your firebase project data (which is public information) and used them on their website, users will not be able to login.

you can view authorized authentication domain in `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[yourProjectID]/authentication/providers`
then to answer your question you set

```
{
     "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

this will allow only authenticated users on an authorized domain to use the database